# How to sync mysql db between 2 localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

i want to develop some php stuff with a friend together. We managed to sync our local projects with an subversion repository on unfuddle.com and with subclipse. Now we need to now how to synchronize the local mysql databases, too. (We both use xampp and we want to use Mysql Workbench to mange the tables)

It's not an option for us to use an online database, because we want to able to write and test code offline.

I'm really a noob at mysql dbs, i just know how to let my php work with them.
so a programm or a eclipse plug-in which could let use the unfuddle repository would be perfect.

Thank you very much,

Someonelse

Comment: Send each other your bin logs :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a bad idea to share a development database. It makes it very difficult to get consistency when other people may be modifying your data. It will very likely interfere with your thought process while coding.

I would recommend adding your database schema (or snapshots) to the svn repository and load them on each database instead. Once you get more comfortable with this, you can start looking at using an ORM like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) to manage your database schema and preferably a whole framework like [Symfony](http://symfony.com) as well.

Now, if you're really stubborn about doing this (and a little crazy too) If you're in the same LAN, look at [master-master](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql5_master_master_replication_debian_etch) replication.. It might work remotely too, but depending on the amount of data being read/written it might be really laggy. Again, you'll likely end up having problems regardless of what route you go with if you decide to share a single db.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont quite undestand everything, but its ok. My friend knows more about this, maybe he knows what to do.

I think the master-master replication is what we want, but why is it laggy? The dbs dont dont neeed to sync on every edit, just when we want them to

Comment: master-master is real time, and there's no standard way to make them sync only when you want them to.. If that's what you want, I'd recommend you add a snapshot to your source control instead, then load it to your database.

Comment: also.. if you're learning source control from scratch, you might as well use git instead. It's much better and faster than svn. Here's a good tutorial: http://codingsnippets.com/getting-started-with-git/

Comment: thanks for the clarification and recommendation.
we'll probably use the snapshot solution.